# pass argument in selector for scheduleTimerwithTimeInterval

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, selector

In swift, I have a uitableviewCell that has double tap and single tap implemented. The double tap works. However, I am having a bit of trouble with single tap. Due to the present of double tap, I implemented single tap with a timer. The following code successfully prints out "Single Tapped"

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    var now = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970

    if (now - lastClick < 0.3) && indexPath.isEqual(lastIndexPath) {
        // Double tapped on cell
        if let cell = discoverTableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CommentCell {
            cell.doubleTapCellActive({ (addBumpStatus, success) in
            })
        }
        singleTapTimer?.invalidate()

    } else {
        singleTapTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.31, target: self, selector: #selector(DiscoverVC.singleTapped), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
    }
    lastClick = now
    lastIndexPath = indexPath
}

func singleTapped() {
    print("Single tapped")
}
```

However, the problem is, I want the single tap to know which index path was selected. I tried doing something like

```
#selector(DiscoverVC.singleTapped(_:indexPath))
func singleTapped(indexPath: NSIndexPath) {}
```

But this gives me an error as selector does not like this syntax. Is there a way to make the selector work or a better way of doing it?

Thanks,

Comment: why you are using NSTimer for double click ? you can use gestures also.

Comment: All I have in the table is three labels, I dont think you can add gesture to a cell? I didnt want to add gesture to everything inside the cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to implement the action with the `NSTimer` parameter

```
func singleTapped(timer : NSTimer) {
   print("Single tapped", timer.userInfo!["indexPath"] as! NSIndexPath)
}
```

and pass custom data via the `userInfo` property of the timer for example

```
singleTapTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.31, 
                         target: self, 
                         selector: #selector(singleTapped(_:)), 
                         userInfo: ["indexPath":indexPath], 
                         repeats: false)
```

Comment: Seems like the way to go. But when i trie to retrieve timer.userInfo as! NSIndexPath, I get a crash with some EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code= 1, address= 0x18) Error. I even changed the selector to "singleTapped:" just to make sure an argument can be passed

Comment: My example is supposed to work. I specified the `userInfo` parameter as a dictionary.

Comment: Works now. Thanks heaps. I was trying to get the userInfo after the timer is invalidated. Which is prohibited.